# Затемнение Активности при использовании SlidingDrawer

Tags: android

Использую в своем проекте стандартный `SlidingDrawer` для панели, выплывающей сверху/снизу.

```
<SlidingDrawer
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:content="@+id/persinfo"
    android:handle="@+id/bookmark"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/persinfo"
        layout="@layout/pers_menu" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/bookmark"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:rotation="180">

       ...
    </FrameLayout>

</SlidingDrawer>
```

Как настроить затемнение основной активности при выдвижении панели?

Пробовал вставить `Layout` с черным прозрачным `background`, который в случае выдвижения становился видимым, но происходит слишком резкая смена цвета. А нужно постепенную (в зависимости от выдвинутого %)

И еще вопрос. `SlidingDrawer` считается устаревшим, но что пришло ему на смену (чтобы можно было вытаскивать снизу/сверху)?

Answer (score 1):

`DrawerLayout` заменил `SlidingDrawer`. 
Для `DrawerLayout` нету значений "Gravity.BOTTOM" или "Gravity.TOP"
Подробней здесь:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/DrawerLayout.html#openDrawer%28int%29

Но вы также можете попробовать это, может поможет
https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel

Comment: да, `DrawerLayout` не получается сделать сверху (или снизу). А SlidingUpPanel пробовал, там другая проблема - нельзя задать отступ по краям (чтобы была видна часть активности). В любом случае, спасибо. Видимо, альтернатив не так и много.

Comment: Пожалуйста, постарайтесь публиковать развернутые ответы содержащие конкретный пример минимального решения, дополняя их ссылкой на источник. Ответы–ссылки (как и комментарии) не добавляют знаний в Рунет.